# add elements to map if Map<String , Stack<Integer>> map... in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Map` collection which maps `String` to `Stack<Integer` how can I put my stacks to this map?
I've tried this so far but couldn't succeed.

```
Map<String,Stack<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("abc",new Stack<Integer>().push(123));
```

Comment: can you please help me to solve this problem how can I add elements if values are in the stack format

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please format your code and add a little description of the problem you're facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please edit and provide a complete Question and not just a code block?

Comment: `new Stack<Integer>().push(123)` returns a `Integer`

Comment: `new Stack<Integer>().push()` will return an `Integer`.

Comment: map.computeIfAbsetnt("abc", k -> new Stack<>()).push(123)

Comment: Next time when asking a question just add some explanation so that anyone who is reading your question can understand, what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: actually I'm trying to add elements in map like (String,Stack<integer>) and internally stack maintain int values for single key
the format is
map.put("abc",12)
map.put("abc",34)
map.put("abc",56)
map.put("abc",78)

so key=abc && value=12,34,56,78

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the super ancient old `Stack` class? Even its documentation says to not use it anymore and instead use `List` and `Queue` etc.

Comment: yes we have a specific reason to do this instead of stack we can use queue also

if I want to delete top element only

if I use get operation in map it will return values but I want to remove top most value and it will go down this is the actual process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Stack#push](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E)) method returns an `Integer` here. You can modify your code this way to achieve it:

```
Map<String, Stack<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(123);
map.put("abc", stack);
```

**Update:**

After looking at your comment on my answer. I think you want to accomplish something like this:

```
Map<String, Deque<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(); // use Deque instead of Stack
map.put("abc", deque); // putting the Deque in Map
map.get("abc").add(12);
map.get("abc").add(34);
map.get("abc").add(56);
map.get("abc").add(78);

System.out.println("Before removing: " + map);
map.get("abc").remove(); // removing first element
System.out.println("After  removing: " + map);
```

Output:

```
Before removing: {abc=[12, 34, 56, 78]}
After  removing: {abc=[34, 56, 78]}
```

Comment: @Andreas well, I just showed him how to achieve what he wants to achieve here. He is not putting the `Stack` in the `Map` rather he's putting the `Integer` value returned after calling the `push` method of the stack *(which is a Syntax error)*. Definitely, if he doesn't check whether a `key` is not already present in the map then it will always replace it with a new `Stack` having only one element.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion can please look at this map.put("abc",12) map.put("abc",34) map.put("abc",56) map.put("abc",78) so key=abc && value=12,34,56,78 if I want to delete top element only if I use get operation in map it will return values but I want to remove top most value every time

Comment: @NiranjanV `Map` can only store one value against a key. Probably you will have a collection to store `12, 34, 56, 78` values.

Comment: yes it can hold values like below
{abc=[100, 129, 367, 124, 243]}

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your valuable time for me

Comment: @NiranjanV You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **computeIfAbsent()** method which was added in Java 8:

```
Map<String, Stack<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("abc", k -> new Stack<>()).push(123);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion

can please look at this

map.put("abc",12) map.put("abc",34) map.put("abc",56) map.put("abc",78) so key=abc && value=12,34,56,78

if I want to delete top element only if I use get operation in map it will return values but I want to remove top most value every time

Comment: use ``map.computeIfPresent("abc", (k,v) ->{ v.pop(); return v;}`` or ``m.get("abc").pop();``

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is wrong here . You have to create object first of type `Stack<Integer>` . As you have specified `Stack<Integer>` as `values` you should have to create `Object` of that type . Return type of `push` is of `type` itself so it cause error in your case.

```
    Map<String,Stack<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(123);
    map.put("abc",stack);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion can please look at this map.put("abc",12) map.put("abc",34) map.put("abc",56) map.put("abc",78) so key=abc && value=12,34,56,78 if I want to delete top element only if I use get operation in map it will return values but I want to remove top most value every time

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch the stack, that you want to update, then you need to update the stack with the new element, and finally use the property of map, that replaces the elements, of the map already exists.

```
Stack<Integer> st = map.getOrDefault("abc",new Stack<Integer>());
st.push(123);
map.put("abc",st);
```

Comment: Will fail if there is no `Stack` (yet) for key `"abc"`.  --- Also, the `put()` is updating the object that is already in the map, so no need to `put` is back in.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was just trying to give him an idea not exactly a code that will compile, but thanks anyway

Comment: The updated code is wasting resources, creating a new `Stack` that is likely to be discarded. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517619/5221149) for how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
BiFunction<Stack<Integer>, Integer, Stack<Integer>> bi = (s, i) -> {
        s.push(i);
        return s;
    };

    map.put("abc", bi.apply(map.get("abc"), 134));
```